# Perl CGI. Can I be sure of the order of <style> tags I use?

Tags: css, perl, cgi

If I create two style strings, like so

```
my $style =<<'EOF';  
<-- @import url("foo.css"); -->  
EOF  

my $style2 =<<'EOF';  
<-- #thing_in_foo.css_that_I_want_to_override a {attributes;} -->  
EOF
```

And I wish to include them in start_html like so:

```
print $q->start_html({  
  -style => [
             {-code=>$style},  
             {-code=>$style2}
]);
```

Or some such.
The long-term goal is to subclass the CGI module with a mess of defaults.  I want to let the user pass some additional hash references to the object, like so:

```
my $q = subCGI->new({-code=>$style2});
```

The object will within build the start_html parameters, and I'd like to put that hash reference into the -style array.  I plan to have some already in there; the intent is to have the user pass any css in the new() parameter such that it will cascade over the defaults.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Why are you even trying this? Keys in a hash ref are unique, so one is going to overwrite the other (so you aren't including two style elements). If you wanted to include two `@import` statements, then you can do it in a single `<style>` element (and save quite a few bytes while having more readable code). The HTML comments around the CSS are cute, but we don't need to protect Netscape 2.0 from decade old HTML constructs any more. And I wouldn't recommend using the HTML generating bits of CGI.pm anyway, template languages are much nicer (I recommend Template-Toolkit).

Comment: Further to the above, the solution to the problem that I suspect you have is: `-style => { -code => q{ @import url("foo.css"); #thing_in_foo.css_that_I_want_to_override a {attributes;} } }`

Comment: I fixed it.  I don't always type what I mean ;)  The point is, I'd like to be able to subclass the CGI function in such a way that one can pass additional hash references to that -style key and be sure they override in the correct order.

Comment: Also this is going on an AIX box I can't control, so Core modules only.

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=693828 — Yes, even you can use CPAN

Comment: See also http://www.shadowcat.co.uk/blog/matt-s-trout/but-i-cant-use-cpan/

Comment: The answer I needed was in these comments.  Mainly the second one by Mr Dorward.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Any subsequent additions to a hash using the same key as used previously will always overwrite the first.  That is,

```
my %hash = (
     key => "value 1",
     key => "value 2",
);
```

...will *always* yield a key with value "value 2", never "value 1".

It is a somewhat common technique to use this to allow optional overrides, e.g.:

```
sub wrapper_around_something_common
{
     # get optional options from the caller
     my %options = @_;

     some_other_function(
         key_1 => 'some default',
         key_2 => 'another default',
         %options,      # and override with any options provided by user
     )
}
```